# SELECTing and displayig data from a database onto a form

Tags: c#, sql, select, sql-server-ce, database-connection

I have an existing Database created in sql server compact edition (inbuilt in visual c# 2010). I need to select and display data from this database on to a form. My code provided gets the form unresponsive.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;Data              Source=ContactName.sdf;database=ContactName"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string intero = "SELECT Name,Company FROM People";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(intero);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            lbFound.Items.Clear();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                lbFound.Items.Add(rdr["Name"].ToString() +
                " " + rdr["Company"].ToString());
            }

            rdr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: _unresponsive?_ What is that mean? Did you debug your code?

Comment: It gets hanged for a while and then shows exception un-handled highlighting the line "conn.open()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using SQL Server Compact, use SqlCeDataReader, SqlCeCommand and SqlCeConncetion. In addition, change your connection string to: Data Source=C:\folder\databasename.sdf

Comment: Error in :-
using (conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=ContactName.sdf;database=ContactName"))

Error Warning:"Unknown connection option in connection string: database."